# What's the JavaScript equivalent of vbcrlf (from visualBasic10)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, alert, msgbox

When I used VisualBasic10, if I needed a Msgbox to display different values on multiple lines, I would terminate each line with vbcrlf (carriage return line feed); so that each string and return value would be displayed simply on its' own line. In JS I still use window.alerts to test values at runtime, but cannot display different values on their own line in the popup alert. I'm guessing this is a pretty basic question. Can someone give me a basic answer which definitively qualifies as an answer?

Comment: The near-universal code in web development is `&nbsp;`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (\n\r added within a string).

```
    function DisplayAlert() {
        var scrWid= document.documentElement.clientWidth; //Get screen width.
        var scrHi=document.documentElement.clientHeight ; //Get screen height.
        
        var jsnl = "\r\n"; //carriage return and newline.
        var msg = ("ScreenWidth is " + scrWid + jsnl +  "ScreenHeight is " + 
        document.documentElement.clientHeight);
        alert(msg);
     }
```